# SQL Alchemy ORM tables on-demand

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Running into something guys and was hoping to get some ideas/help. 
I have a database with the tree structure where leaf can participate in the several parents as a foreign key. The typical example is a city, which belongs to the country and to the continent. Needless to say that countries and continents should not be repeatable, hence before adding another city I need to find an object in the DB. If it doesn't exist I have to create it, but if for instance country doesn't exist yet, then I have to check for the continent and if this one doesn't exist then I have to have creation process for it. 
So far I got around with the creation of a whole bunch of items if I run it from the single file, but if I push the SQL alchemy code into module the story becomes different. For some reason meta scope becomes limited and if the table doesn't exist yet, then the code start throwing ProgrammingError exceptions if I query for the foreign key presence (from the city for the country). I have intercepted it and in the `__init__` class constructor of the class I am looking for (country) I am checking if the table exists and creating it if doesn't. Two things I have a problem with and need an advice on:
1) Verification of the table is inefficient - I am working with the Base.metadata.sorted_tables array through which I have to look through and figure out if the table structure is the one that matches my class `__tablename__`. Such as:

```
for table in Base.metadata.sorted_tables:
    # Find a right table in the list of tables
    if table.name == self.__tablename__:
        if __DEBUG__:
            print 'DEBUG: Found table {} that equal to the class table {}'.format(table.name, self.__tablename__)
        if not table.exists():
            session.get_bind().execute(table.create())
```

Needless to say, this takes time I am looking for more efficient way to do the same.

2) The second issue is with the inheritance of the declarative base (declarative_base()) with respect to the OOP in Python. I want to take some of the code repetitions away and pull them into one class from which the other classes will be derived from. For instance code above can be taken out into the separate function and have something like this:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class OnDemandTables(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'no_table'
#    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('id'), nullable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    def create_my_table(self, session):
        if __DEBUG__:
            print 'DEBUG: Creating tables for the class {}'.format(self.__class__)
            print 'DEBUG: Base.metadata.sorted_tables exists returns {}'.format(Base.metadata.sorted_tables)
        for table in Base.metadata.sorted_tables:
            # Find a right table in the list of tables
            if table.name == self.__tablename__:
                if __DEBUG__:
                    print 'DEBUG: Found table {} that equal to the class table {}'.format(table.name, self.__tablename__)
                if not table.exists():
                    session.get_bind().execute(table.create())

class Continent(OnDemandTables):
    __tablename__ = 'continent'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('id'), nullable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(64), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, session, continent_description):
        if type(continent_description) != dict:
            raise AttributeError('Continent should be described by the dictionary!')
        else:
            self.create_my_table(session)

            if 'continent' not in continent_description:
                raise ReferenceError('No continent can be created without a name!. Dictionary is {}'.
                                     format(continent_description))
            else:
                self.name = continent_description['continent']
        print 'DEBUG: Continent name is {} '.format(self.name)
```

The problem here is that the metadata is trying to link unrelated classes together and requires `__tablename__` and some index column to be present in the parent `OnDemandTables` class, which doesn't make any sense to me.

Any ideas?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to post the solution here for the rest of the gang to keep it in mind. Apparently, SQLAlchemy doesn't see the classes in the module if they are not being used, so to say. After couple days of trying to work around things, the simplest solution that I found was to do it in a semi-manual way - not rely on the ORM to construct and build-up the database for you, but rather do this part in a sort of manual approach using class methods. The code is:

```
__DEBUG__ = True

from sqlalchemy import String, Integer, Column, ForeignKey, BigInteger, Float, Boolean, Sequence
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm.exc import MultipleResultsFound, NoResultFound
from sqlalchemy.exc import ProgrammingError
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, schema
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()


engine = create_engine("mysql://test:test123@localhost/test", echo=True)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False)
session = Session()
schema.MetaData.bind = engine

class TemplateBase(object):
    __tablename__ = None

    @classmethod
    def create_table(cls, session):
        if __DEBUG__:
            print 'DEBUG: Creating tables for the class {}'.format(cls.__class__)
            print 'DEBUG: Base.metadata.sorted_tables exists returns {}'.format(Base.metadata.sorted_tables)
        for table in Base.metadata.sorted_tables:
            # Find a right table in the list of tables
            if table.name == cls.__tablename__:
                if __DEBUG__:
                    print 'DEBUG: Found table {} that equal to the class table {}'.format(table.name, cls.__tablename__)
                if not table.exists():
                    if __DEBUG__:
                        print 'DEBUG: Session is {}, engine is {}, table is {}'.format(session, session.get_bind(), dir(table))
                    table.create()

    @classmethod
    def is_provisioned(cls):
        for table in Base.metadata.sorted_tables:
            # Find a right table in the list of tables
            if table.name == cls.__tablename__:
                if __DEBUG__:
                    print 'DEBUG: Found table {} that equal to the class table {}'.format(table.name, cls.__tablename__)
                return table.exists()


class Continent(Base, TemplateBase):
    __tablename__ = 'continent'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('id'), nullable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(64), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, session, provision, continent_description):

        if type(continent_description) != dict:
            raise AttributeError('Continent should be described by the dictionary!')
        else:

            if 'continent' not in continent_description:
                raise ReferenceError('No continent can be created without a name!. Dictionary is {}'.
                                     format(continent_description))
            else:
                self.name = continent_description['continent']
        if __DEBUG__:
            print 'DEBUG: Continent name is {} '.format(self.name)
```

It gives the following:
 1. Class methods is_provisioned and create_table can be called during initial code start and will reflect the database state
 2. Class inheritance is done from the second class where these methods are being kept and which is not interfering with the ORM classes, hence is not being linked.

As the result of the Base.metadata.sorted_tables loop is just a class table, the code can be optimized even further removing the loop. The following action would be to organize classes to have their tables checked and possibly created in a form of a list with keeping in mind their linkages and then loop through them using is_provisioned and, if necessary, create table methods.

Hope it helps the others. 
Regards